# Aligning HTML List

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a HTML list that is using background images in oppose to text as links. My container is 200px tall and I want the links to lie inline in the center of the container, if this were text I could use a line-height:200px; to achieve this however it seems a little different when using background images, any body have any idea how to achieve this method.

Here is a jsfiddle to explain what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/M4XN4/1/

Thanks guys

```
<div id="container">
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"></a><li>
        <li class="twitter"><a href="#"></a><li>
        <li class="facebook"><a href="#"></a><li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful with 2 elements having the same id. id attributes should be unique as oppose to classes. Also your closing <li> tags do not prefix with / ie: </li>

Comment: Ah! I see, though this has not the solution. I have however amended my jsfiddle and code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned a bit up, is this the look you were going for?

Most of your a tag code can stay separate from each .facebook .linkedin class as well

```
#footer-right ul li a{
display:inline-block;
height:200px;
background-size:14px 14px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
line-height:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ush4n/13/

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks @kilrizzy

Comment: Sweet! If you have any specific questions about what I did just let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline` and some margins to vertical align.

```
margin-top:80px;
```

Comment: I could, however I want to avoid using vertical margins so I can keep my footer responsive.

Comment: You can wrap the container of this and the container of the footer and make it relative. Then You can use absolute positioning to lay the footer on top margin. (If the footer is not on top use z-index)

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, changing the ul to `position: relative;` and positioning it to `top: 72px` did it.

The value of top was calculated by subtracting 14px (height of the ul) + 14px (the empty space over the ul) from 100px (vertical center of the containing div).

You can see the updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/M4XN4/2/